# Merge MySQL columns exclude duplicates

Tags: mysql, merge, move

I have these two tables:

```
desc students
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| student_id            | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| student_ticket_number | int(11) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc studentdates
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| student_date_id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| student_id            | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| student_ticket_number | int(11) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to move the column `students.student_ticket_number` to `studentdates.student_ticket_number` where the field `student_id` match.

So if the user John has `student_id` = 1 move his ticketnumber (for example 1234) from `students.student_ticket_number` to `studentdates.student_ticket_number WHERE student_id = '1'`.

In the table `studentdates.student_id` there can be multiple identical records then I would like to use the lowest `studentdates.student_date_id` and skip the others. Tell me if this is unclear.

I guess I need to do a subquery somehow but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the minimum `student_date_ID` in a subquery then join it with the other tables. try this,

```
UPDATE  students a
        INNER JOIN studentdates b
            ON a.student_ID = b.student_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  student_ID, MIN(student_date_ID) minID
            FROM    studentDates
            GROUP BY student_ID
        ) c ON b.student_ID = c.student_ID AND
               b.student_date_id = c.minID
SET     a.student_ticket_number = b.student_ticket_number
WHERE   a.student_id = '1'
```

```
UPDATE  students a
        INNER JOIN studentdates b
            ON a.student_ID = b.student_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  student_ID, MIN(student_date_ID) minID
            FROM    studentDates
            GROUP BY student_ID
        ) c ON b.student_ID = c.student_ID AND
               b.student_date_id = c.minID
SET     b.student_ticket_number = a.student_ticket_number
WHERE   a.student_id = '1'
```

Comment: Hello, thank's for the reply. This looks good however I need to `UPDATE` the table `studentdates` not the `students` but I guess I can toss everything around in your query :)

Comment: @David does this work by interchanging their alias `SET b.student_ticket_number = a.student_ticket_number` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Update studentdates sd,students s,(select student_id,min(student_date_id) as minstudDateId from studentdates group by student_id) sm
SET sd.student_ticket_number = s.student_ticket_number 
where sd.student_id=s.student_id
and sd.student_id=sm.student_id
and sd.student_date_id=sm.minstudDateId
```

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'sd' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Hello, I went with John Woos query. Thank you however for taking the time. Upvoted your post